# How does "href=#" close the modal box?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand how clicking the close link will close the dialog.

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#openModl" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

            <h2>Modal Box</h2>

        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;

    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #bbb;

}
.close {
    background: #777777;
    color: #Fbbbbb;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

Comment: there must be some javascript code behind click event of your modal close link

Comment: no click event this all the code you can try in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the link #openModal is clicked the :selector is activated and thus the opacity is set to 1.
when you click on the #openModl(not the same as #openModal) is clicked, the :target is being removed and opacity goes back to 0.
simple ;-)